# Ubicación de las rutas de Auth::routes() en Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

En otras versiones estaban en:

`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php`

pero no están en ese archivo actualmente.

Quiero eliminar de la lista el Registro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recordemos que desde la versión 6 del framework, el comando `php artisan make:auth` que nos generaba un scaffolding para la autenticación y registro ya no se encuentra presente, por que su funcionalidad fue movida a un [paquete por separado](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend#introduction).

Es importante hacer notar que todavía para esta versión, las rutas quedaban declaradas en la misma ubicación, [que aquí podemos consultar en el repo oficial](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php).

Sin embargo en el caso de Laravel 7, la ubicación ahora se encuentra en la clase `AuthRouteMethods` del namespace `Laravel/Ui` dentro del método `auth` cuya ubicación exacta luego de instalar dicho *package* es:

- Carpeta principal

  - carpeta vendor

    - laravel

      - ui

        - src

          - AuthRouteMethods.php

Comment: Mil gracias nuevamente BetaM, siempre dispuesto a ayudar! ya lo solucioné con tu respuesta.